# Arrays first index displaying wrong element

Tags: c#

I am currently studying C# language and getting 0 on the first index[0] where I am looking to see the user input which is "yx".

Here's what I have written:

```
using System;
namespace Examples
{
    class arrays
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] y = new int[7];
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your array y0: ");
            int yx = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your array y2: ");
            int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            foreach (var newemptyarray in y)
            {
                y[0] = yx;
                y[2] = y2;
                Console.WriteLine(newemptyarray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please, can someone clarify the fact in details?

Comment: What's your question? As it is now, your output should be: `0`, `0`, <y2>,  `0`,  `0`,  `0`,  `0`. Is it not?

Comment: As written, there is no need for the for loop

Comment: If the title is actually your question: The foreach iterates all elements in the array. Since you get the first (`[0]`) element before you assign it, you get `0` for the first output. (Also you assign it 7 times in total because it's in the loop - which you probably didn't intend.)

Answer (score 2):

This loop doesn't do what the code suggests you think it does:

```
foreach (var newemptyarray in y)
```

That's iterating over the elements in `y`, which are *integers*. So `newemptyarray` isn't an array, it's just a value. On the first iteration of the loop, it will be the value of `y[0]`... but it's the value of `y[0]` *before* it enters the loop body, therefore it will always be 0. A `foreach` loop doesn't set up a special association with the array such that every time you access the iteration variable it fetches it from the array.

If you rearrange your code to:

```
y[0] = yx;
y[2] = y2;
foreach (var value in y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Then it will display `yx`, then 0 (for `y[1]`) then `y2`, then a bunch more zeroes.

You could also simplify the code to remove `yx` and `y2` entirely, just assigning directly into the array:

```
int[] y = new int[7];
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your array y0: ");
y[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your array y2: ");
y[2] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
foreach (var value in y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] y = new int[7];
```

Here you created an array of 7 integers.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your array y0: ");
        int yx = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Here you ask user to input an integer, which is stored in a variable yx.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your array y2: ");
        int y2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Here you ask user to input another integer, which is stored in a variable y2.

```
        foreach (var newemptyarray in y)
```

This ForEach loop will help you "Read" each item from the array.

```
        y[0] = yx;
```

You assign 0th item in the Array to (1st) user input in variable yx. -- Why??

```
        y[2] = y2;
```

You assign 2nd item in the Array to (2nd) user input in variable y2. -- Why??

```
        Console.WriteLine(newemptyarray);
```

This statement will print the Current Item in the Loop (i.e. It will print entire Array one item at a time) - I guess your output is

```
0 0 y2 0 0 0 0
```

Where y2 is the value user inputs from Console.
Edited :- Read Enumerator to understand why yx is not appearing in output.

Comment: The point is that the first line of output *isn't* `yx`, it's `y2`, because `newemptyarray` is being assigned *before* `y[0]` is ever assigned, hence the first line of the question.